# C#: How to GET an image from an API with credentials?

Tags: c#, image, api, authentication, get

I'm trying to make an API call using the simplest way possible:

```
<img src="http://IP-ADDRESS-TO-API/api/call/camera=1">
<img src="http://IP-ADDRESS-TO-API/api/call/camera=2">
```

**IN CHROME**: (the above code will pull the first image, but not the second almost every time)

**IN EXPLORER**: (the above code will only pull the first image AFTER prompting the user for the `username` and `password`)

**The 'IP-ADDRESS-TO-API' is actually not the same IP or domain as where I'm calling it from.** If I call the address from an AJAX call, I get a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` error.

I'm attempting to call this via C# to see if it can bypass this with the proper header sent in. Is there anyway to call this API call while passing in a `username` and `password`?

I've looked at examples of doing this via `WebRequest` but sadly, I can't see any methods of passing in credentials via the call itself. This as well as actually returning a proper image back to the DOM. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) object?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see anywhere where I can actually pass in `username` and `password` to make the `WebRequest`. the only thing I see is `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`.

Comment: Then you might want to look at creating and passing in a [NetworkCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71b57yke(v=vs.110).aspx) object ...

Comment: OK great! so this solves half of my problem. towards the end, where it says `WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse(); `, How can I pass this then to my UI